# Writing nested dictionaries to JSONs?

Tags: c#, json, winforms, dictionary, nested

ive got a nested dictionary as such Dictionary1<double, Dictionary2<string, string>> that I would like to write to a json.
Dictionary2 is created from textboxes as such: Dictionary2<textbox.name, textbox.text>

I have tried writing this data to a JSON however only double from Dictionary1 appears in the json.

```
public void Write_JSON()
        {
            dictionary_JSON.Clear();
            Dictionary<string, string> tempdic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            tempdic.Clear();
            foreach (double d in available_doubles_values)
            {
                foreach (TextBox t in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                {
                    tempdic.Add(t.Name, t.Text);
           
                }
                dictionary_JSON.Add(d, tempdic);
                tempdic.Clear();
            }

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary_JSON, Formatting.Indented);

            File.WriteAllText(@"limits.json", json);
        }
```

however what shows up in the json is:

```
"double1": {}, 
"double2": {}, 
"double3": {},
```

the dictionary2 tempdic is not being written. What am i missing?

Comment: ...if this is all the code you are using, none of the data in `tempdic` makes its way to `dictionary_JSON`.  Are you missing a step where `tempdic` should be added as a Value to `dictionary_JSON`?  (P.S. It might be nice to show sample code that defines the type of `dictionary_JSON`, moving closer to the goal of having a minimally reproducible example.)

Comment: I don't know how you are getting anything at all in the string `json`. The only times you use it in this code is to `clear` it and then serialize it.  There must be some code missing.  (Also, there is no need to clear a dictionary just after creating it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do Clear it removes the elements of the dictionary that's why you have nothing in the json. You need to realocate a new Dictionary each time you enter the first for.
I also replaced test_limits_json by dictionary_JSON since that was probably the point.
Try that:

```
public void Write_JSON()
    {
        dictionary_JSON.Clear();
        
        
        foreach (double d in available_doubles_values)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tempdic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (TextBox t in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                tempdic.Add(t.Name, t.Text);
       
            }
            dictionary_JSON.Add(d, tempdic);
            
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary_JSON, Formatting.Indented);

        File.WriteAllText(@"limits.json", json);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes you were correct that by test_limits_JSON i meant dictionary_json. I have edited and reflected this in my OP. This solved my issue